# Etherscan status difference between pending and indexing

Tags: etherscan, pending-transition

I've been checking block status and then I got wonder that I can't see pending in RinkebyScan but indexing.

The reason I check this is because I want to speed up my tx so I need to send new tx with higher gas when tx I sent is pending. But it always says it's indexing so my tx with higher gas make a new transaction not replacing the latest.

But in mainnet I could see pending status so I want to ask the difference and can't I see pending in Rinkeby?

This screenshot is from mainnet:

[image]

Indexing screenshot is from Rinkeby:

[image]